# How can I reconstruct my codes to fit the following GUI

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe

I want to make the interface more beautiful,for the components inside the JPanel p1 are too large.My reputation is not enough to allow me to put the image,so I just display my source code.I want to perform like this:
[image]

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame{
    private JButton b1 = new JButton("登陆"),b2 = new JButton("注册");
    private JTextField userName = new JTextField(),password = new JTextField();
    public TestFrame(){
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,10,10));
        p1.add(new JLabel("用户名："));
        p1.add(userName);
        p1.add(new JLabel("密码："));
        p1.add(password);
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.add(b1);
        p2.add(b2);
        add(p1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(p2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        b1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        b2.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    }
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if (e.getSource() == b2){
                if (userName.getText().equals("") || password.getText().equals("")){
                    System.out.println("用户名和密码不能为空");
                }
                else if (User.getCount() == 0){
                    User.setUserName(userName.getText());
                    Password.setPassword(password.getText());
                    System.out.println("succeed");
                }
                else if (User.isUserName(userName.getText())){
                    System.out.println("用户名已存在");
                }
                else {
                    User.setUserName(userName.getText());
                    Password.setPassword(password.getText());
                    System.out.println("succeed");
                }
            }
            if (e.getSource() == b1){
                if (User.isUserName(userName.getText()) && Password.isPassword(userName.getText(),password.getText())){
                    System.out.println("登陆成功");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else System.out.println("登陆失败");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        TestFrame frame = new TestFrame();
        frame.setTitle("欢迎");
        frame.setSize(400,300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need to use another `LayoutManager`, because of `GridLayout` resize component to whole cell(horizontally/vertically). Try to use `FlowLayout` if you needn't resizing or [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

For example change constructor like next :

```
 public TestFrame(){
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    p1.add(new JLabel("用户名："),c);

    c.gridy = 1;
    p1.add(new JLabel("密码："),c);

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridx = 1;
    p1.add(userName,c);

    c.gridy = 1;
    p1.add(password,c);
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    p2.add(b1);
    p2.add(b2);
    add(p1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(p2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    b1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    b2.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `frame.setSize(400,300);` call `frame.pack()`, which will set the size of the frame according to your components.